# Security of bcrypt iterations/cost parameter

Tags: security, hash, passwords, password-protection, bcrypt

Fact A. Based on Pigeonhole Principle, every hash functions has infinite number of collisions, even if none is found yet.

Fact B. Re-hashing a hash, like hash(hash(password)) is not more secure than hash(password), actually hash(hash(password)) open up a collision attack that is not possible with hash(password).

Fact C. Based on B, by increasing iterations, we reach a point that most passwords and salts will return same constant hash value. I mean probability of colliding will be high, even 100%.

Fact D. bcrypt has a iteration/cost parameter that we can increase over time, based on our hardware specifications.

So, by combining this facts, can we say that with a higher bcrypt cost value, we decrease security by increasing probability of colliding?
If answer is "no", why?

Comment: Fact B is [dubious](http://arstechnica.com/staff/2014/12/ars-was-briefly-hacked-yesterday-heres-what-we-know/?comments=1&post=28141599).

Comment: @zneak, Lets look at this example: hash(s1)=X and hash(s2)=Y. But if hash(X) = hash(Y) ***collision occurred*** then hash(hash(hash(s1))) and hash(hash(hash(s2))) and all other hashes after this will be equal. In an infinite iterations - based on fact A - all hashes for all passwords will be equal. So, never use hash(hash(password)), because is not secure at all.

Comment: Your concern is that hashing iterations become harmful as soon as a collision occurs. How does this balance against the concern that brute-force against single-iteration hashes is trivial? Naively, hashing passwords twice divides hashing throughput by two. I am skeptical to the claim that chances of collision do worse than doubling in the same conditions.

Comment: Also in contention of Fact B: [good hash functions preserve entropy very well](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10402). Also consider how hard it is to formulate a collision or pre-image attack on good hash functions: for most functions, it's not any *theoretically* easier than a brute force search, which implies that the initial collision is so unlikely as to be effectively zero. There is a wide gulf between the *infinite* iterations for this to become a problem and *computationally many* iterations needed to deter brute-force attacks.

Comment: English is not my mother tongue and I can't understand what are you trying to say.  But, if I got it correctly, I want to say that It is better to use password and salt in every iterations as martinstoeckli said that Bcrypt & PBKDF2 are using this approach too. (take a look at accepted answer). So if hash(pass1+salt1+hash(pass1+salt1)) and hash(pass2+salt2+hash(pass2+salt2)) produce same value, hash(pass1+salt1+hash(pass1+salt1+hash(pass1+salt1))) will not be equal to hash(pass2+salt2+hash(pass2+salt2+hash(pass2+salt2))).

Comment: @Patrick M, Lets say that you are Satia Nadella and you want to use admin panel of microsoft. Programmers used 1000 iteration for password hash, and in 700th one, output value for your password, Mr. Satia Nadella, which is "Piahf8(^%@#Gdgii" is equal to a value that me, the normal user is testing just for curiosity: "123456". Is it more secure than no iteration? I don't think so. I know that probability is very few after 1000 iteration (Actually just 0.5^125 in md5 in average case), but it is not zero, and it is 1000 times lower than actual collision probability of md5 which is 0.5^128.

Comment: I'm not mathematician or security expert, so numbers may be not really correct, so, don't focus on accuracy of numbers.

Comment: Your fist comment about "hash(pass1+salt1+hash(pass1+salt1))" is exactly correct. Without going into exact numbers, you're right that it's not zero chance. My point is that it's effectively zero chance, especially when compared to the computational feasibility of other attack vectors, including the rest of the work required to complete a brute force attack.

Comment: @PatrickM: I see. I really understand that what you are trying to say. You are saying that the chance is so low that we can say that it never happens in practice. But, nobody can prove that the "Satia Nadella's example" never happens.

Comment: I wrote this up in more depth in [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011233), but the other factor you're overlooking is that for a collision to be impactful, it has to occur on the *same iteration*. Due to the deterministic nature of hash functions, that means a collision after *n* iterations is no more likely than after 1, 2, ... *n-1* iterations. If hash(s1) == hash(s2), then hash(hash(s1)) == hash(hash(s2)), but that's entirely dependent on the first collision occurring, which is vanishingly improbable (for good hash algorithms for inputs less than the output width).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BCrypt does not do stupid iterations, it includes the original password and the salt in every iteration. The same goes for PBKDF2, which uses a HMAC in every iteration. Have a look at the [pseudo code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) of BCrypt.

There is a very [illustrative answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/10661/8343) on *Information Security* about the effects of collisions with iterative hashing. In praxis, as far as i know, collisions are not really a problem for password hashing, even when iterated.

Comment: Does the word "stupid" apply to something specific here?  Is it a term of art in cryptography?

Comment: @Glyph - No, what I meant with stupid iterations is what you can see quite often when somebody tries to implement key-stretching: a simple `for` loop of hashing, using the output as input of the next iteration. Actually this would even work, because an attacker would have to do the same and spends more when brute-forcing. Password-hashing algorithms do not work like this though, they combine the original salt in a more complex pattern with the input of an iteration, to generate the output of the iteration.